# MySQL random select doesn't return anything

Tags: mysql, select, random

I am trying to make a app that generates a random username. I have a simple table with just an ID and a name column. Basically:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dude |
| 2 | chill |
| ... | ... |

I want to select 3 random values from there. This is my attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO @count -- gets the length
FROM username_generator;
 
SELECT name FROM username_generator -- selects 3 names with random IDs
WHERE id IN (
    (FLOOR(RAND() * @COUNT)+1), 
    (FLOOR(RAND() * @COUNT)+1),
    (FLOOR(RAND() * @COUNT)+1)
);
```

The idea is that it counts the length and selects 3 IDs inside the length range.

The problem is that this sometimes returns NOTHING and I can't figure out why. The random numbers are always in the range and I have names in the table. Eg:

Normal:

[image]

Not normal:

[image]

Comment: Are there any gaps in your `id`? I mean can you guarantee that the `MAX(id)` is equal to `COUNT(id)`, and every consecutive value from 1 to max is used on a row?

Comment: I only have 15 names in because I'm trying it out so I can 100% guarantee it.

Comment: You know the count, but that does not guarantee there are no gaps. Try `SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id), COUNT(id) from username_generator` and confirm that the min is 1, and the max and count are equal.

Comment: You can also try this: `SELECT r.id, name FROM (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * @COUNT)+1 AS id UNION SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * @COUNT)+1 UNION SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * @COUNT)+1) AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN username_generator USING (id);` Run it a few times and see if you get NULL for the name sometimes.

Comment: The MIN was 1 and MAX and COUNT were the same. I've ran your solution a few 10x times and it seems to be working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is there could be gaps in the id range.

The simplest way around this, and indeed the simplest solution, is to forget about using count and just pick 3 names randomly as follows:

```
select name
from username_generator
order by rand()
limit 3
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd27418/1) (refresh the demo page to see different names being returned each time the query runs).